Write String values in Writer object with Java 8 Stream
I'm trying to replace an ordinary for loop which writes String values in a Writer object with stream in the following code:
public void save() {
    try (Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
        fileWriter.write("someStrings\n");

        ArrayList<ParentType> parentList = super.getParentType();
        for (ParentType parentTypeObj : parentList) {
            fileWriter.write(toString(parentTypeObj) + "\n");
        }

        ArrayList<ChildType> childList = super.getChildType();
        for (ChildType childTypeObj : childList) {
            fileWriter.write(toString(childTypeObj) + "\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ManagerSaveException();
    }
}

public static String toString(ParentType parentTypeObj) {
    if (parentTypeObj == null) return null;
    String result = "";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
    if (parentTypeObj instanceof ChildType) {
        String startTime = parentTypeObj.getStartTime().format(formatter);
        String endTime = parentTypeObj.getEndTime().format(formatter);
        result = Integer.toString(parentTypeObj.getIdNum()) + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getName() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getStatus() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getDescription() + ","
                + ((ChildType) parentTypeObj).getSpecId() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getDuration().toMinutes() + ","
                + startTime + ","
                + endTime + ",";
    } else {
        String startTime = parentTypeObj.getStartTime().format(formatter);
        String endTime = parentTypeObj.getEndTime().format(formatter);
        result = Integer.toString(parentTypeObj.getIdNum()) + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getName() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getStatus() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getDescription() + ","
                + parentTypeObj.getDuration().toMinutes() + ","
                + startTime + ","
                + endTime + ",";
    }
    return result;
}

How to do it?
Expected to write String values in a Writer object via Stream.

"Trying to replace ordinary for loop ... with stream" why? What benefit do you think it will provide?

that's learning task

Given it throws IOException, which is a checked exception, that is harder to do than is worth it, IMHO.

without seeing how toString(...) is declared and implemented, only guessing... better include a [mre] (reproducible means enough to execute it)

straightforward, functional approach: super.getParentType().stream() .map(this::toString) .map("%s%n".formatted) .forEach(fileWriter::write) - only possible if toString(...) is declared to not throw any checked Exception

@user85421 That won't work because FileWriter.write throws an IOException, and a Consumer as expected by forEach does not accept checked exceptions.

posted own toString()

@Mark true, I forgot about the IOException... maybe eventually better to use a PrintWriter (despite I prefer having to handle an IOException instead of not having it)

Basically that should looks like (same for childList):
ArrayList<ParentType> parentList = super.getParentType();
parentList.stream()             // Stream<ParentType>
    .map(p -> toString(p)+"\n") // Stream<String>
    .forEach(fileWriter::write);

Alas, write method may throw an exception, and this is forbidden with the Stream API. You then have to, either:

(Option 1) encapsulate the write method in a method that manages internally the exception.

    .forEach(s -> {
        try {
            fileWrite.write(s);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // internally catched
        }
    })


(Option 2) or chain the exception into a Runtime one to get it outside the Stream.

    .forEach(s -> {
        try {
            fileWrite.write(s);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException("Bang!",e); // so that it can be catched outside the Stream by chaining it to a RuntimeException.
        }
    })

---EDIT---
Same reasoning must be applied to the method toString if it throws something...

BTW original code is using own toString(...) method(s) instead of Object.toString() , and we do not (yet?) know that method - does it just call Object.toString()? does it throw an IOException?

@user85421 right! need an update...

but your proposal is not using toString(...), which takes an argument as posted in question - it is using Object#toString() (which does not throw any checked Exception)

It might be better to use java.io.UncheckedIOException instead of a generic RuntimeException.

@user85421 See EDIT at the end. But worst, we don't know what toString() returns, it may return anything else than a String. I think OP is able to correct it if needed.
